# HTML.fromHTML - TagHandler in Android

Tags: java, android, html

I have a TextView and I want to set HTML to it with:

```
  HTML.fromHTML();
```

But I want to filter out all the `<Img>` tags with a taghandler and I want to save all links (src) in a List Array. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Yoo can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (Java HTML Parser) for easy HTML parsing i.e.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements img = doc.select("img");
for (Element el : img)
{
    String imageUrl = el.attr("src");
    images.add(imageUrl);
}
```